# Wordpress: Author Settings Not Found instead of Page

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a question about Wordpress blog.
I have posts and pages with different content.
On one day, the instead of any page in my blog I see the message "**Author Settings Not Found**". But posts are displayed normally.

In other words, posts and categories work perfectly but pages are affected by this technical issue.

I tried to search solution of this problem but it's unclear: I can see just webpages with the same problems but not an advice how to fix it.
I'll be much appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a couple of hours to find the issue.
Since I see that over 400 websites in the Internet, which are built on Wordpress, have the same notifications, I will share my own experience how to fix this problem. Perhaps, it will be useful for someone.

In my case, I re-installed Wordpress, deactivated plugins related to pages and page management but nothing helped.

Then I deactivated the plugin "About Author" (in my case it was "Version 1.4.7 | By Weblizar") and the pages returned to their previous place.

I don't have the problem anymore. Pages are displayed.

Hence, if you have "Author Settings Not Found" - deactivate this plugin, because it overlaps the basic settings for author in Wordpress.
Thanks!